# Java print binary number using bit-wise operator

Tags: java, bitwise-operators, bit, bitwise-and

Hi I am creating a method that will take a number and print it along with its binary representation. The problems is that my method prints all 0's for any positive number, and all 1's for any negative number

```
private static void display( int number ){

        System.out.print(number + "\t");        
        int mask = 1 << 31;

        for(int i=1; i<=32; i++) {
            if( (mask & number) != 0 )
                System.out.print(1);
            else
                System.out.print(0);


            if( (i % 4) == 0 )
                System.out.print(" ");

        }

    }
```

I got it: this works:

```
/**
     * prints the 32-bit binary representation of a number
     * @param number the number to print
     */
    private static void display( int number ){
        //display number and a tab
        System.out.print(number + "\t");

        //shift number 31 bits left
        int mask = 1 << 31;

        //loop and print either 1 or 0
        for(int i=31; i>=0; i--) {
            if( ((1 << i)&number) != 0)
                System.out.print(1);
            else
                System.out.print(0);

            //every four bits print a space
            if( (i % 4) == 0 )
                System.out.print(" ");            

        }
        //print new line
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to update the mask:

```
    for(int i=1; i<=32; i++) {
        if( (mask & number) != 0 )
            System.out.print(1);
        else
            System.out.print(0);


        if( (i % 4) == 0 )
            System.out.print(" ");

        mask = mask >> 1;
    }
```

Comment: Depending on type of `mask`, the shift needs to be unsigned `>>>`.

Answer (score 2):

The text of the question has been edited numerous times, so it's hard to tell what the question is, but here are some remarks.

#### On signed vs unsigned shift

One revision of the question contains this line:

```
int mask = 1 << 31;
```

One answer suggests that what was missing is this line:

```
mask = mask >> 1;
```

This actually won't work, because `>>` is a signed shift, and would result in the incorrect `mask` value for this purpose (since emptied bits are filled with `1`s). Any negative number would be converted to 32 bits, all `1`.

What is needed is the unsigned right shift.

```
mask >>>= 1;
```

Note that compound assignment has been used for brevity. Unsigned right shift `>>>` fills emptied bits with `0`. As used here, it ensures that `mask` will always have only one bit set, which is what is required for this problem.

#### See also

- [JLS 15.19 Shift Operators](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.19)
- [JLS 15.26.2 Compound Assignment Operators](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.26.2)

#### Similar question

- [program with java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690115/program-with-java)

  - A similar homework assignment

---

#### Alternative solution

There's actually a simpler solution to convert a 32-bit `int` into 32 bits, separated into groups of 4 bits.

```
static String zeroes(int length) {
    return (length <= 0) ? ""
      : String.format("%0" + length + "d", 0);
}
//...

int num = 8675309;

// convert to binary
String s = Integer.toBinaryString(num);
System.out.println(s);
// prints "100001000101111111101101"

// fill in leading zeroes
s = zeroes(Integer.SIZE - s.length()) + s;
System.out.println(s);
// prints "00000000100001000101111111101101"

s = s.replaceAll("(?!$)(?<=\\G.{4})", " ");
System.out.println("[" + s + "]");
// prints "[0000 0000 1000 0100 0101 1111 1110 1101]"
```

Even if this is homework, the variety of techniques used here should still be instructional.

#### See also

- [`Integer.toBinaryString`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString%28int%29)
- [`java.util.Formatter` syntax](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)
- [regular-expressions.info/Lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)